# Função de erro complementar em java?

Tags: java, matemática

Como calcular função de erro complementar em java ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, tem algum exemplo do que já fez? Ou de como é esta função? Ficaria mais fácil de ajudar!

Comment: Editei a pergunta dá uma olhada pra ver se ajuda.

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski é essa função do excel "erfc" quero saber de como fazer ela com java. o nome dela é função de erro complementar. não estou encontrando nada

Comment: Veja aí: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/jacoco/org.apache.commons.math3.special/Erf.java.html

Comment: Já agora: erfc(x)=1-erf(x).

Comment: Alexandre funcionou cara . mas to curioso com uma coisa por que sempre temos que subtrair por menos 1 ?

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto  Porque a função erfc(x) é definida a partir da função erf(x). A primeira é apenas uma conveniência para não se estar sempre a escrever 1-erf(x). A função erro (erf) permite calcular a probabilidade segundo a distribuição normal. A erfc é o complementar dessa probabilidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione essa dependência ao projeto.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Basta chamar esta função.

```
double vlr = Erf.erf(x);
System.out.println("valor" + vlr);
```